# 403 forbidden when communicating between docker services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

I am trying to create an app in the microservices architecture, and I seem to have problem running all the apps together.

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./Frontend
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    links:
      - proxy
  proxy:
    build: ./Proxy
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - foods
  foods:
    build:
      ./FoodMicroService
    container_name:
      foods
    links:
      - database
  database:
    image: postgres
    container_name:
      database
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_DB: wildCats
```

When I do the calls from Frontend to Proxy on localhost:8080 it works. However, I try to call a get request from foods:3001 in proxy, I get:
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 353ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3932)
proxy_1     |
proxy_1     |
proxy_1     |
proxy_1     | RestClient::Forbidden (403 Forbidden):

EDIT: apparently the problem was from the foods service, ruby wanted

```
config.hosts << 'foods'
```

in config/environments/development.rb

Comment: This does not seem a docker networking issue. Did you inspect the proxy log when called by foods?